# I'm unable to convert my Src IP column into type integer using Python

Tags: python, pandas, ip-address, data-conversion

I am currently attempting to apply `int` to this column type, but it's throwing me an error.

```
int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(df['Src IP']))
```

My error traceback is:

```
AddressValueError: Expected 4 octets in '0 
172.27.224.251\n1        
172.27.224.251\n2        
172.27.224.250\n3        
172.27.224.251\n4        
172.27.224.250\n              
...      
\n22619    
172.27.224.251\n22620    
172.27.224.251\n22621    
172.27.224.251\n22622    
172.27.224.251\n22623    
172.27.224.251\n
Name: Src IP, Length: 22624, dtype: object
```

Comment: Because `IPv4Address` works at one string at a time; not on a whole Pandas series (dataframe column). Use something like `.map()` or `.apply()`.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include your actual dataframe structure printed here as code.

Comment: Hey Nathan, its a CSV file I generated it from CICFLOWMETER. I'm a novice in coding your help is appreciated. Here is the link to the file https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ugrtMH6UkPbUZrVSqy940qe6LjVB-cfj?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['new'] = df['Src IP'].map(ipaddress.IPv4Address).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
               Src IP         new
0      172.27.224.251  2887508219
1      172.27.224.251  2887508219
2      172.27.224.250  2887508218
3      172.27.224.251  2887508219
4      172.27.224.250  2887508218
22619  172.27.224.251  2887508219
22620  172.27.224.251  2887508219
22621  172.27.224.251  2887508219
22622  172.27.224.251  2887508219
22623  172.27.224.251  2887508219
```

Comment: I used your code it still shows similar error.

Comment: Update your post with the output of `print(df.head())`

Comment: Index(['Src IP', 'Src Port', 'Dst IP', 'Dst Port', 'Protocol', 'Timestamp',
       'Flow Duration', 'Total Fwd Packet', 'Total Bwd packets',
       'Total Length of Fwd Packet', 'Total Length of Bwd Packet',
       'Fwd Packet Length Max', 'Fwd Packet Length Min',
       'Fwd Packet Length Mean', 'Fwd Packet Length Std',
       'Bwd Packet Length Max', 'Bwd Packet Length Min',
       'Bwd Packet Length Mean', 'Bwd Packet Length Std', 'Flow Bytes/s',
       'Flow Packets/s', 'Flow IAT Mean', 'Flow IAT Std', 'Flow IAT Max','Flow IAT Min', 'Fwd ....]. It includes a total of 84 columns.

Comment: You probably have bad IP addresses in your list. Try: `sr = df.loc[~df['Src IP'].str.contains(r'^(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}$', ), 'Src IP']`. Is `sr` is empty?

Comment: df['Dst IP'].iloc[0:22600]= df['Dst IP'].iloc[0:22600].map(ipaddress.IPv4Address).astype(int)
I tried this it worked with first 256 columns. Alright I'll try your code as well.

Comment: 15270    Src IP
Name: Src IP, dtype: object this the output I got.

Comment: This is the output of `sr`?

Comment: 15270 Src IP Name: Src IP, dtype: this is the output

Comment: You have 15270 bad IP addresses over 22624 records???